# Get an Graphic to Stay in Same Place Relative to H1 Text

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I'm trying to get a small yellow swoosh to underline a word in some text and stay where it is as the page resizes. Right now I can get the swoosh in the right spot under the text, but when the screen resizes it all goes to hell.

Here is an image of what I'm going for [image]

```
<div>
  <span>
<h1>How are you doing? Hello World.</h1>
<img src="imageurl here">
  </span>
</div>

div {
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;

}

span {
   margin-left: 140px;
   top: 40px;
   position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

(I didn't want to share the image URL as it is proprietary)

Any ideas on how to achieve this type of effect responsively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your image inside of the h1 tag and give your h1 tag a position property. Also make sure you are setting h1 to be a inline-block element and center it somehow.

```
<h1>How are you doing? Hello World.<img src="imageurl here"></h1>

h1{
  text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

img{
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

There are many different ways to achieve what you're after.